# How to run tests with target directory only (where test classes are compiled to)?

Tags: scala, sbt

I use sbt **0.13.5**.

I'd like to execute tests on a machine and given they're successful move the project to another machine and rerun them without compilation.

I tried `sbt testOnly package_1 package_2` but it didn't work.

These are the steps of what I am trying to do:

1. Compile the project using `sbt clean compile`. If I execute `sbt testOnly myTest1` on this machine, it works fine.
2. Create a zip file from everything in `target`
3. Downloads the file on another machine
4. Extracts it and run tests. (I only have `target` directory on this machine.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to execute tests without some subset of build definition, i.e. you don't have all the dependencies of the project under tests. What's inside `target` is just the compiled sources you wrote in the project - there are no test libraries. sbt won't help you without helping sbt itself first.

You may mimic what sbt does with transitively downloading `test` and `compile` dependencies, but it's far too much work comparing to copying the build definition to the other machine.

What *may* work is to have `build.sbt` and `target` directory in a single (semi)project on the other machine. `sbt test` should work fine then (don't use `clean` for obvious reasons).

Comment: I copied `build.sbt`, `target/`, and `project/` but it didn't work. Do you have other suggestion?